# TypeScript в React и Redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

Пытаюсь разобраться c TypeScript в Redux, есть такой rootReducer:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { TEST_CONST } from '../actions/actionTypes'

interface state {
    result: string
}
const initialState: state = {
    result: 'test'
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TEST_CONST:
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

export default store
```

Все работает как должно, кроме одного момента: в строке `const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {` редактор вполне ожидаемо ругается на параметр **action**, так как он имеет тип any. Однако если я поставлю ему какой-то тип (например, **action**: *string*), то редактор ругается уже на следующую строку, то есть `switch (action.type)` выдает мне `Property 'type' does not exist on type 'string'`. Возможно, это глупый вопрос, но может эта проблема просто решается тем, что я поставлю какой-то специальный тип для параметра action? Буду благодарен за помощь в понимании этого вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Что ж, нашел такую альтернативу: файл actionTypes полностью удаляем и создаем интерфейс Action:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

interface stateTypes {
    result: string
}
interface Action {
    type: 'TEST';
    TEST: string
}

const initialState: stateTypes = {
    result: 'test'
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TEST':
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

export default store
```

В дальнейшем, чтобы использовать несколько экшенов, можно использовать такую конструкцию:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from "redux";
import thunk from "redux-thunk"

interface stateTypes {
    result: string
}
interface ActionOne {
    type: 'TEST';
    TEST: string
}
interface ActionTwo {
    type: 'FOO';
    FOO: string
}
type Action = ActionOne | ActionTwo

const initialState: stateTypes = {
    result: 'test'
}

const rootReducer = (state = initialState, action: Action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TEST':
            return state
        default:
            return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
)

export default store
```